# Comparing a field type array with a variable in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to do this from Node.js:

```
var usr=new Array();
usr[0]=23;

collection.find({'content': {'$all': query},'usrblocked':{'$nin':usr},'type': 'usr'}).toArray(function(err, items) {
                                    res.jsonp(items);
                                });
```

The problem is that `'usrblocked'` is an array with a `'usr'` variable, would it be posible to do this, for example:

```
[14,25] not contains 23
```

Comment: It's not apparent to me what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I want this, for example the field 'usrblocked' is an array like this [14,25,30] but I need to know if contains the value 23 or not

Comment: So why not just do `db.collection.find({usrblocked:23});`?

Comment: That does not work, because 'usrblocked' is a field that contains an array

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can query arrays like that. It will match every document where one array-entry is equal to 23.

Comment: ok, forgive me, that works, but what I really need is db.collection.find({'usrblocked':{'$ne':23}}) and this does not work as I need

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41726/discussion-between-alexander-ceballos-and-philipp)

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, this works, even if `usrblocked` is an array:

```
'usrblocked':{'$ne':usr}
```